# XPages EventHandler actionListener with this.action - actionListener does not fire

Tags: jsf, xpages, actionlistener

I am working on a XPage.

I have a managedBean for it ContractsBean.  In ContractsBean I have a method saveContract().

On the XPage I also have a datasource bound to a document in another NSF, its variable is the standard #{document1}.

Parts of the page data is coming from a NSF file and other parts of the page from DB2.

I am working on saving the page with , some of the data goes to the NSF and the other to DB2.  I first worked with the NSF, and saved the data successfully using document1.

I then added a ActionListener to call a event listener and the event listener didn't fire.  I remove the  save document1 and the ActionListener fires normally.

Is it I cannot have both a xp:this.action and actionListeners in the same event handler?

Any JSF gurus, this may seem familiar...

```
<xp:button value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"
                styleClass="btn green pull-left">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="norefresh" immediate="true">
                    <xp:this.action>
                        <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
                    </xp:this.action>
                    <xp:this.actionListeners>
                        <xp:actionListener
                            type="com.page.listeners.SaveContractListener">
                        </xp:actionListener>
                    </xp:this.actionListeners>
                </xp:eventHandler>

            </xp:button>
```

Now if I do this, remove the xp.this.action it works, the action listener fires.

```
<xp:button value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"
                styleClass="btn green pull-left">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="norefresh" immediate="true">

                    <xp:this.actionListeners>
                        <xp:actionListener
                            type="com.page.listeners.SaveContractListener">
                        </xp:actionListener>
                    </xp:this.actionListeners>
                </xp:eventHandler>

            </xp:button>
```

If I cannot have both in a EventHandler, what is the alternative to use the ActionListener to get a handle to document1 (how?) and save it in my actionListener?

Comment: did you get that source only by "clicking" in designer? in that case it might be a designer bug. otherwise (writing xml markup by yourself), your code isn't translated to model/html output properly.

Comment: I used domino designer to configure it.  Are you saying, it should not have left me do this? It doesn't complain on a build.

Comment: No, I am saying you can type source the way it can be compiled, but not working as expected. At the other hand, sometimes Designer UI may produce the source that way. I was just curious. Seems you made it work with added action group. That' the the second one from above mentioned cases :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work using this markup

```
<xp:button value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"
                styleClass="btn green pull-left">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete" disableValidators="true" immediate="true">
                    <xp:this.action>

                        <xp:actionGroup>
                            <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>

                        </xp:actionGroup>
                    </xp:this.action>

                    <xp:this.actionListeners>
                        <xp:actionListener
                            type="com.page.SaveContractListener">
                        </xp:actionListener>
                    </xp:this.actionListeners></xp:eventHandler>

            </xp:button>
```

Comment: This technically works, however with the immediate="true", my model is not updated from the UI so the listener always has the old bean values.  I guess I need a way to access the DataSource document1 in the listener.  This solution applies best to actions that do not require updating models, like navigation or recording users visiting the page, ect...

Comment: If there is a validation error or a error trying to bind the model with the UI (JSF Phase 4 - Update Models), then "Invoke Application" will never run and you jump to render response.  Having phase listeners helps while watching the logs during unit testing your code.